# Text search in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to make a stored procedure that would make it possible to search text. My goal is to make a stored procedure for search. I want the result when I EXEC it would get the list of Lastname so that I can search it. For example "James", then I want all James to be displayed using the stored proc.

Here is my code:

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE spGetUser
@Description varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Lastname, Firstname FROM Users
    WHERE Lastname LIKE '%'
    ORDER BY Lastname
END
```

Comment: LOL, I'm first :) This was easy, the difficult thing was to type faster...

Answer (score 2):

You need this:

```
WHERE Lastname LIKE '%' + @Description + '%'
```

Where @Description is the substring to search for.

Answer (score 0):

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE spGetUser
@Description varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Lastname, Firstname FROM Users
    WHERE Lastname LIKE '%' + @Description + '%'
    ORDER BY Lastname
END
```